# apt-get Perl 5.18.2 in debian:wheezy with threading support

Tags: perl, debian, apt-get, apt, perlbrew

I'm trying to install perl 5.18.2 with threading support in ubuntu using apt-get (binary installation, not from source)

Basically, the equivalent of the following perlbrew-based installation

```
perlbrew install -v perl-5.18.2 -Dusethreads -n --as perl-5.18.2_WITH_THREADS
```

in apt-get method:

```
sudo apt-get install perl perl-base
```

But the above apt-get command installs an older version and has no way to get perl compiled with threading support. Is there a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/perl/5.18.2-2ubuntu1) hosting perl 5.18.2 compiled with threads binary? If so, what is the apt-get command to install from it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Trusty (14.04 LTS) appears to already be using a suitable Perl build.

Comment: Yup, I use Ubuntu Trusty (14.04 LTS). It ships with 5.14.2. But I'd like to install Perl 5.18.2

Comment: Are you **sure** that's the version you're using? http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/perl/perl says it should be 5.18.2.

Comment: @alpha_cod no, trusty ships 5.18.2. 5.14.2 is in the release a good two years older.

Comment: Oh...sorry, just checked yes. My host has 5.18.2. I'm trying to install this in a dockerized environment running debian:wheezy which has Perl 5.14.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

Debian uses Perl internally for a number of system management tasks — it's a critical system component. As the Perl ABI changes between major versions, and all of the Perl modules in Debian are compiled against the version of Perl that was supplied with that release, you can't safely replace the system Perl with another version. Trying to do so will result in a completely broken system.

If you want a different Perl version than the one that came with the Debian release you're using, you'll need to install it to an alternate location (e.g, using perlbrew), or use another Debian release and/or distribution.

Comment: Oh, its not practical to expect some PPA shipping a higher Perl version for Debian:wheezy is it, since that'll break the entire system?

Comment: Correct. It'd break compatibility with every binary that links against Perl, including Perl modules as well as binaries which embed libperl.